# Можно ли считать слова "определённо" и "абсолютно" усилителями отрицания?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Можно ли считать слова "определённо" и "абсолютно" усилителями отрицания?
Только что возник вопрос насчёт этого, а в интернете данная тема не затронута.

Comment: Иногда полезно добавить в вопрос пример употребления интересующего Вас выражения. Или Ваш вопрос в том, всегда ли эти слова усиливают отрицание?

Answer (score 2):

Слова ***определенно*** и ***абсолютно*** могут усиливать утверждение (**слитное** написание НЕ), если они относятся к прилагательным и образованным от них наречиям:

Как мы видели, первое необязательно верно, а второе **определённо неверно**. [А. А. Зализняк. Лингвистика по А. Т. Фоменко // «Вопросы языкознания», 2000]

Независимость в передвижении и **абсолютно непредсказуемый** маршрут делают тебя неуязвимым для преследования.

Но при наличии других зависимых слов  НЕ может писаться   **раздельно**:

На уровень продаж влияет множество дополнительных факторов, **абсолютно не связанных** с рекламой...

Раздельное написание НЕ с причастием при наличии зависимого слова ***с рекламой***.

Comment: *...усиливают утверждение (слитное написание НЕ)...* — Определённо не согласен :)

Comment: Возражение было не столько о раздельном написании, сколько об "усилении утверждения". Другой пример: выражение "определённо нет" усиливает отрицание, а не утверждение.

Comment: "Не согласен"  пишется только раздельно, там нет выбора. А пример с раздельным написанием даже при наличии "определенно" приведен в ответе. Так что здесь действует более весомый фактор, который определяет раздельное написание.  А при наличии выбора эти наречия подчеркивают утвердительное значение.

Comment: Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77Если в качестве пояснительного слова выступает наречие меры и степени (весьма, крайне, очень, почти или наречное выражение в высшей степени и т. п.), то частица не с прилагательным всегда пишется слитно: весьма некрасивый поступок; крайне неуместный выпад; очень неудачное выступление; почти незнакомый текст; в высшей степени неразборчивый почерк.

Comment: Здесь говорится о наречиях степени, отнесенных к прилагательным и качественным наречиям.  Наречия "определенно, абсолютно" могут выражать такие значения. А вот НЕ с глаголами пишется преимущественно слитно, никакие наречия на это повлиять не могут.

Comment: Это понятно. Дело не в слитном или раздельном написании. Вопрос ведь был об усилении отрицания, а не утверждения. Вряд ли автор вопроса не знала, что эти слова могут усиливать утверждение.

Comment: А мне непонятно. Надо было вопрос отредактировать, он некорректен. Указанные наречия не являются усилителями чего-либо, такого термина нет.  Но есть слова, по которым можно определить утвердительное или отрицательное значение прилагательных (наречий).  Это довольно узкая тема, которая  рассматривается  именно  в орфографии (выбор слитного/раздельного написания).

Comment: Я считаю, что когда вопрос непонятен или некорректен, лучше его уточнить (это можно сделать в комментарии к вопросу). Также Вы имеете право отредактировать вопрос (это лучше делать всегда, когда Вы видите явные ошибки в вопросе). В противном случае Ваш ответ может неправильно понять не только спрашивающий, но и другие участники.

Comment: Точно. Просто некогда было редактировать, очень торопилась. Но я так и думала, что с этим вопросом у меня будут проблемы. Удалите ответ, если он Вам не нравится, я не возражаю.

Comment: Хороший ответ, не обращайте внимания. Я просто вчера хотел его чуть дополнить в шуточной манере, не более того.

Answer (score 2):

Эти слова не имеют "отрицательной" специализации, но могут использоваться и при усилении отрицания, с некотороми ограничениями в употреблении для второго слова.

"**Определённо**" выражает *уверенность* говорящего (усиление - только в этом аспекте) в утверждении или отрицании чего-либо и синонимично наречиям "**явно**" и "**безусловно**". Это слово нейтрально по отношению к утверждению или отрицанию фактов, качеств и прочего, выражаемого самыми разными частями речи:

> он определённо (не) хочет этого, это определённо (не)съедобный гриб,
>   это определённо (не)сложно сделать, это определённо (не) он сделал

Слово же "**абсолютно**" (синоним "**совершенно**") отрицает относительность **качества** или его *меры* и приписывает ему крайнюю степень выражения, поэтому оно сочетается преимущественно с *прилагательными*, некоторыми *причастиями* (краткими и полными), а не с существительными или глаголами. Например, выражение "*это абсолютно не он сделал*" порой можно услышать, но воспринимается оно как просторечие (правильнее было бы "безусловно" или "явно") - здесь на самом деле нескладно выражена "абсолютная уверенность". Примеры с усилением отрицательного качества:

> это абсолютно несъедобный гриб, он абсолютно не приспособлен к такой
>   жизни, это абсолютно непонятно