# Можно ли слова «совершенно» и «абсолютно» использовать для проверки написания частицы НЕ?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

1. Мы очень любим простые решения, особенно **метод подстановки,** да еще ссылаемся при этом на Розенталя. Но вот я в очередной раз убеждаюсь в ненадежности этого метода.

Внимательно читаю справочники Розенталя и Лопатина и делаю такой вывод. Да еще прихожу к мнению, что и справочники-то мы обычно читаем **«по диагонали».**

И думаю о том, что каждое предложение **конкретно и индивидуально**, так что метод проверки срабатывает не всегда.

2. Поводом для моего рассуждения послужила **тема,** которой  мы не уделили нужного внимания, а именно такой вопрос  (об усилительных словах) ставился уже там. Правда, речь шла и о других вопросах, но я хочу обсудить именно **эти наречия**. Уж они-то всегда вызывали  к себе доверие, магия самих слов))

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467781/Влияние-наречий-меры-и-степени-на-написание-НЕ-с-причастиями-на-количество-Н-в](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467781/%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9D%D0%95-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%9D-%D0%B2)

Но мы и раньше обсуждали эту тему, но в той дискуссии нет краткого и точно сформулированного мнения. [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444078/Можно-ли-считать-слова-определённо-и-абсолютно-усилителями-отрицания](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444078/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

3. Мне же хочется **короткий** ответ (с **небольшим** обоснованием)  именно в таком **формате**: можно ли или нельзя использовать эти слова для проверки, ссылаясь при этом на справочники Розенталя и Лопатина.

**P.S.**  Хочу подчеркнуть такую деталь: наречия н**е задают** написание НЕ, а **влияют** на написание как усилители. К примеру, если НЕ с глаголами пишется раздельно, то это уже  не изменить. Аналогично на написание НЕ с причастиями бОльшее влияние будут оказывать другие **зависимые** слова, но не усилительные.

Мне интересна прежде всего **ПРАКТИКА**. Эти наречия используют школьники при анализе, да и мы в своих ответах. Точно ли **различаются** правила Розенталя и Лопатина? Может быть, они говорят об одном и том же?..

Буду очень благодарна вам за обсуждение и ответы, но сама комментировать ответы пока не буду. Мне хочется послушать именно вас.

Спасибо.

Comment: Когда не срабатывают? Всегда срабатывают! Вы неправильно использовали "так что", одно из другого не следует.

Comment: Буду очень благодарна вам за обсуждение и ответы, но сама комментировать ответы пока не буду. Мне хочется послушать именно вас.

Comment: Когда не срабатывают? Всегда срабатывают! Вы неправильно использовали "так что", одно из другого не следует.

Comment: **Как можно писать "срабатывает не всегда" просто так, чисто из несимпатии?**

Comment: А чего это они различаются? Вроде бы в этой теме нет противоречий.

Comment: Он абсолютно не узок и определенно не красный. Он определенно не высокий и определенно невысокий.